# tcl - running widget launch using tclsh & wish on windows 10 has display issue

Tags: tcl

I have a widget program launched using tclsh and wish - they work good on windows 7. but on windows 10 they widget label,entry,tablelist scroll doesn't appear in correct position. What might be going wrong?

I use padx and grid combination for the widget placement.

Comment: Could you include a simple picture of what it looks like when it has gone wrong and a bit of code? That would help us figure out what the problem is. (I'm guessing it's related to scaling or highDPI display handling in some way.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: I will get a sample code as the actual is confidential. I do see the issue discussed in http://wiki.tcl.tk/9595 . but wondering if there is a solution for highDPI settings. I will modify the screen resolution to check. thanks for quick resonse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the display resolution of screen. Changing to smaller value <125% on windows 10 and 1920x1080 on windows 7 worked. For more information on alternative workarounds http://wiki.tcl.tk/9595.
Appreciate all suggestions.